# Issue Related to Virtual Directory in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, web, localhost, virtual-directory

I am new to ASP.NET and IIS stuff
I have a Web Application in MVC Framework..

i wanted to create a virtual directory for this application in my local machine.
so i added in iis using **"Add Virtual Directory.."** and given physical path..

but my problem is- when i change code in .cs file from visual studio, and hit refresh in browser without buid in visual studio - broswer doesn't reflect the result...

So is it necessary to buid an application after change ? or is there any extra settings required in iis to reflect the result in browser without build...

Thanks....

Comment: It is not related to IIS. MVC requires compiled code to reflect the changes.

Comment: If the change is in the View - then you don't need to rebuild the project. If the change is in the code (e.g. in the Controller) then you have to build the solution. 

This is changed in ASP.NET 5 where we have a dynamic compilation, so even after change in the C# - there will be no need for rebuild, but just refresh the browser.

http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/aspnet-5-overview